# How do you get the Contract JSON Interface from Truffle?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, json-rpc

I'm developing smart contracts using Truffle. I got the contract's bytecode through `truffle compile`. This produced a large json file and it wasn't too ahrd to find the bytecode. Now, how can I find the Contract JSON Interface for easy testing of the contract, especially those that import from multiple files and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the object called `abi: {}`. It might be huge.

Answer (score 2):

Within your truffle test, try this:

```
let Contract = artifacts.require('./Contract.sol');

contract('Contract', accounts => {
    Contract.deployed().then(instance => {

        console.log(instance.abi);

    });
});
```